# Extracting windows/subarrays along a binary circular line/path with view_as_windows from skimage

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, scikit-image

I have an 8bit [binary image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3D6I.png) that shows me the outline of a circle. The outline is only 1 pixel wide. Using the function [view_as_windows](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) lets me generate smaller arrays or windows of an input array like this picture, with adjacent overlapping windows. The size of this image is 250×250.

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

fname = "C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\Circle.tif"

array = imread(fname)
window_shape = (50, 50)
step = 20

new_array = view_as_windows(array, window_shape, step=step)
```

This gives me 11×11 overplapping windows. However, I want to extract only windows **along** the line of the circle so that I can reassemble this object at a later time. The line of a each window should be positioned centrally or in a way so that I have access to the information right under the circle.

This is what I have tried so far:

First I replaced the values (0) and (255) with (1) and (0), respectively. This way, math is a bit easier.

```
array[array==0] = 1
array[array==255] = 0
```

Then I iterated over the windows in `new_array`. In this case over the first two dimensions. `new_array.shape` is (11, 11, 50, 50)

```
for j in range(new_array.shape[0]):
    for i in range(new_array.shape[1]):
        Window = new_array[j, i]
        SliceOfWindow = Slice[20:30, 20:30]
        sumAxis0 = np.sum(Slice, axis=0)
        sumSlice = np.sum(sumAxis0)
        if sumSlice >= SliceOfWindow.shape[0]
            imsave(...)
```

I created a smaller slice of the shape = (10, 10) within each window, placed in the center. If the sum of each slice >= the length of a slice I have saved that array as an image.

Can this be done in a more **precise** way? Is there a way to yield better results (better windows!)?

Comment: If you have a binary mask, you can use `numpy.where` to find the coordinates for those pixels, and manually extract windows through slicing.  Alternatively, you can fit parameters to the circle (center + radius), and then use `skimage.draw.circle_perimeter` to generate the coordinate positions for you.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the circle is close to the edge of the image, where a window would reach past the edge?

Comment: I should have mentioned that getting the coordinates of those pixels is not a problem. And yes then I could easily extract windows of every pixel of that line. However, I want to have e.g. for every 10th pixel of the line a window around this pixel. This however, would require a list of coordinates in the right order, a starting point and endpoint. This was actually my initial idea but I could not find a way to make a list with coordinates that would describe the course of the line. The circle is only an example. Later the shapes will look more like ellipses.

Comment: This function from skimage does not create windows that go past the edge, but I think I know what you mean. My idea was to treat the edges differently. For windows at the edge I would only check if they have any information of the circle in them (without the central slice). If so, I would take them. There are probably better solutions. I hope someone could help.

Answer (score 0):

For a convex curve, you could use polar coordinates and sort the edge pixels by their angle through [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) and [`numpy.arctan2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html).

### Demo

```
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

img = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3D6I.png')

# Arbitrary point inside the curve
row_cen, col_cen = 125, 125

# Coordinates of the edge pixels
row, col = np.nonzero(img == 0)

# Put the origin on the lower left corner
x = col - col_cen
y = -(row - row_cen)

# Indices of the centers of the windows
step = 60
idx = np.argsort(np.arctan2(y, x))[::step]

windows = np.zeros_like(img)
size = 15
for _, n in enumerate(idx):
    windows[row[n] - size:row[n] + size, col[n] - size:col[n] + size] = 255

plt.imshow(windows, cmap='gray')
for i, n in enumerate(idx):
    plt.text(col[n], row[n], i, fontsize='14',
             horizontalalignment='center', 
             verticalalignment='center')
plt.show()
```

[image: Edge and set of windows on the edge]

Comment: I managed to find a solution myself and will provide the code tomorrow. I will also take a closer look at your approach. Thank you very much for the detailed answer.